# Angular2 Javascript Validating Input number not character

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Link to full project (without nodes_modules) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qd8x97ih1f1nho/workinghw4zipped%20%281%29.zip?dl=0

Note: Once you run it, everything about this problem is within the "Edit All" part of the website, click on that to access the table

The purpose of this part of the website is to have the users enter a name and price for each row in the table.

If the user enters a character (not a number) inside price box, then there has to be a "invalid input" message somewhere which updates itself as the user is typing it.

What should I add or change in the code that will allow the user to have an "invalid input" message when entering a character (not a number) into the price box?

The html file:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My Heroes</h2>

<form [ngFormModel]="myForm" class="ui form">
<table *ngFor="#hero of heroes">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Hero Name</th>
      <th> Price </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="id"><label>{{hero.id}}</label></td>
        <td id="name"><input type = "String" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="Pristine name" /></td>
        <div class="field">
        <td id="price">
          <input type = "number" 
          [(ngModel)]="hero.price"
           placeholder="Pristine Price" 
          [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('price')"
          />Input Pristine</td>
           </div>



   <div *ngIf="!sku.control.valid"  
         class="ui error message ">Price can only be an integer.</div>  
       <div *ngIf="sku.control.hasError()"  
         class="ui error message">Input is invalid</div>  
    <div *ngIf="!myForm.valid"  
      class="ui error message">Not pristine.</div>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

The .ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  FORM_DIRECTIVES,
  FormBuilder,
  Control, ControlGroup,
  Validators
} from 'angular2/common';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'SpreadSheetComponent',
  templateUrl: 'app/spreadsheeteditall.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/spreadsheeteditall.component.css'],
  providers: [HeroService],
})



export class SpreadSheetComponent {
  myForm: ControlGroup;
  price;

  onSubmit(value: string): void {
    console.log('you submitted value: ', value);
  }  
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private _heroService: HeroService, private _router: Router) { 
        function skuValidator(control: Control) : { [s: string]: boolean } {
      if (!control.value.match(/[0-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/)) {
        return { invalidSku: true };
      }
    };
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      'sku': ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required, skuValidator])]
    });
 this.price = this.myForm.controls['sku'];
  }

  getHeroes() {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  gotoDetail() {
    this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: this.selectedHero.id }]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Comment: The input type of price control is a number, still it accepts characters?

Comment: the "input type = "number"" is supposed to "block" the user from entering a characters but I still want a way to send a message to the user incase they manage to enter a character in the price field anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work. But this is my solution to your problem. I hope that it works for you.

Replace your input control for price with this -

```
<input type = "number" 
      [(ngModel)]="hero.price"
       placeholder="Pristine Price" 
      [ngFormControl]="myForm.find('price')"
      (keypress)="showErrorIfNotANumber($event)"
      />
```

And then add this tag to show message anywhere you want -

```
<p style="color:red;" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</p>
```

Modify your component.ts file -

1) Add a variable -

```
public errorMessage:any = null;
```

2) Add this function -

```
public showErrorIfNotANumber(event:any){
if(event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57){
    this.errorMessage = null;
}
else{
    this.errorMessage = 'you can only enter numbers here!';
}
}
```

Comment: After implementing and running your code I got these  errors (screenshot): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e71222zvkrmv6qx/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-27%20at%2012.26.44%20PM.png?dl=0

and this next screenshot is what it's supposed to look like except the "This is not a number!" message is going to be replacing the "Input Pristine"


https://www.dropbox.com/s/gsg2rmjligcsgyw/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-27%20at%2012.32.24%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Replace Input pristine with {{errorMessage}} and make sure that your html tags are opened and closed properly(to remove template parse errors)

Comment: I think we're getting close but now I get a different error (see screenshot)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlk9sz8augjcrko/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-27%20at%2012.57.46%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: I think still there is some problem with html. can you share screenshot of your html?

Comment: here https://www.dropbox.com/s/espa9tyevmeco97/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-27%20at%201.17.41%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Unfortunately this is due in ten minutes, I might not be able to add the corrections

Comment: There are so many errors in the html. Remove all closing tags in the bottom and add like this ->  </tr></tbody></table></form>

Comment: adding that at the end gave me unexpected closing tag error :\ it's too late but I'll still give you the check points

Comment: I dont knw what but there might be some silly mistake. I hope your TL might be able to help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can find isNumber by using isNaN function in angular 2.

```
  checkData(username: string, email: string, phone: string, msg: string) {
    if (isNaN(Number(phone))) {
        //code
    } else {

    }
  }
```